# Need a site that will let you create your own html/css template that you can copy and paste to your site?

Tags: html, css, templates

I want to create a site but now I don't have time to create the template so I was wondering if there is a site that will allow me to do what the above question states.

I want to have sounds on there, drop menus, etc.

I did some googleing but I did not find any particular site.

Comment: I want it to be free please because I can't found to buy it now.

Comment: Something like jsFiddle.net? That's an HTML/JavaScript/CSS sandbox, but it's not like 5 fields where ou select a color scheme and the rest is taken care of. However, you could also look in to themeforest.net.

Comment: Thank but I "select a color scheme and the rest is taken care of" and other things

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for : http://www.noupe.com/css/50-free-css-x-html-templates.html

Answer (score 2):

There's one site I go to for templates - either stand-alone html/css or wordpress:

http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates

I think you'll find what you're looking for there.

Best of luck

Comment: Thank you everyone. I found out what I was looking for. This site seem good: http://freehtml5templates.com/